# Datatables mDataProp: val param undefined

Tags: datatables

I'm working on implementing a custom filter value where existing html tags are stripped away for each applicable table column values. 
*(The reason is that filtering the data also accounts for values inside the html tags, and this is not desired.)*

This is a legacy code base, using datatables v1.9.0.

The table is constructed using params, such as aoColumns, aaData.

For table data is using array of arrays: i.e:

```js
aaData = [
   ['12450','<a href='javascript:doStuff(123, 456)>value2</a>', 'User 1', '$500'],
   ['12455','...','...','...'],
   ['12462','...','...','...'],
   ['12314','...','...','...'],
   [...],
   ...
]
```

Table has to use `mDataProp` for applicable `aTargets`
The function signature is:

```js
tableOptions["aoColumnDefs"] = [
    {
        "mDataProp": function (source, type, val) {
            console.log("source ", val); // This returns: row array
            console.log("type ", type); // This returns each type (except for 'set')
            console.log("val ", val); // This returns: undefined
            var obj = {};
            var temp = angular.element('div');
            temp.innerHTML = val;
            if (type === 'set') {
                obj.value = val;
                obj.value_filter = temp.textContent || temp.innerText;
                console.log(obj.value_filter);
                return;
            } else if (type === 'filter') {
                return val;
            } else if (type === 'sort') {
                return val;
            }
            return obj.value;
        },
        "sDefaultContent": '',
        "aTargets": [ 1 ]
    },
]
```

The issue is that `val` parameter inside `mDataProp` always returns `undefined`, so the table data population would error out, if not for the `sDefaultContent` property. 
See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/javlc/k2p77aL3/).

Why cannot the `mDataProp` get the `val` parameter populated? Does `mDataProp` support an array of arrays as data source? *(The documentation is not clear about this)*

Answer (score 0):

After digging through a bit I found out that when `mDataProp` is used as a function, it does not have any reference to the data being passed to the datatable from the javascript array variable, thus returning `undefined` for `val`.

The workaround for this particular case is to use direct array position references in the `source` parameter, depending on the `aTargets` value to be used. (If using `"aTargets": [ 1 ]`, then have to call `source[1]` in the `mDataProp` function).

I did not use `if (type === "set"){}`, 'cause I could not access it.

```js
"mDataProp": function(source, type, val) {              
    var obj = {};
    obj.value = source[1];  // Set column value
    // Process value as desired ...
    obj.value_filter = obj.value + ' foobar';
    // Return value for filtering
    if (type === 'filter') {
      return obj.value_filter;
    }
    // Return original value for display, sort, etc.
    return obj.value;
}
```

Click [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/javlc/k2p77aL3/3/).